# How to stop cellForItemAtIndexPath running if its datasource changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I collect photos from `ALAssetLibrary` and present them in `UICollectionView`. I add a notification called `ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification` to handle photo changes and call showLatestPhotos whenever that notification is posted.
My photo-collection function is like:

```
- (void)showLatestPhotos {
    _latestPhotos = [NSMutableArray array];
    // get photo from asset and inset into _latestPhotos
    [_latestPhotos insertObject:...];
    [_collectionView reloadData];
}
```

The problem is that if I perform a screenshot(click home and power at the same time), ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification is posted more than twice, that is, showLatestPhtots will be executed twice, and the second time when _latestPhotos is set to empty using `_latestPhotos = [NSMutableArray array]`, the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` of the `collectionView's` datasource triggered by `[_collectionView reloadData]` in the first call is still being called and when it call `[_latestPhotos objectAtIndex:],` the application crashes. Anyone know how to solve this bug?

Comment: Show the crash message. It's there for a reason.

Comment: It is of cause bounds exceeding error:   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index *** beyond bounds [0 .. ***]'

Comment: Are you doing things in another thread? The code you posted cannot lead to that exception. Though the problem might be in the omitted part. Telling where it crashes would be helpful too.

Comment: I've already written, mate. It's in cellForItemAtIndexPath:, where I call [_latestPhotos objectAtIndex:]. The_latestPhotos is no longer available here as it has been reset in the second call to showLatestPhotos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a solution. As time interval of ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification trigger by single photo-change such as screenshot is approximately .1 second, I just wait all of them arrive and perform showLatestPhotos only once using `performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:` and cancel previous unnecessary call(s) using `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget: selector: object:` Thank you for answering my question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

use This it will work

```
if ([_latestPhotos containsObject:yourobject] == NO) 
{
   // Do something
   _latestPhotos = [NSMutableArray array];
   // get photo from asset and inset into _latestPhotos
   [_latestPhotos insertObject:...];
   [_collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I don't think it can solve my problem. I think the key is to prevent cellForRowAtIndexPath: and showLatestPhotos from running asynchronously.

Comment: it not loading the collectionview if the newobject is already in your array

Comment: There is no such thing called "yourObject". I just collect all of the photos in the device and call reloadData to refresh the collectionView. If photo changes, then _latestPhotos changes, and view is refreshed. The point is you cannot refresh the view while your datasource is not available because it has been changed by another thread.